# filters.delaunay doesn't work

Tags: point, point-cloud, pdal, pipeline

I have pdal 2.2.0
My pipeline is the following:

```
pipeline = [
        input_path,
        {
            "type": "filters.elm"
        },
        {
            "type": "filters.outlier"
        },
        {
            "type": "filters.sample",
            "radius": 1
        },
        {
            "type": "filters.delaunay"
        },
        {
            "type": "writers.ogr",
            "filename": "outfile.shp",
            "measure_dim": "Z"
        }
    ]
```

However the results WITH and WITHOUT filters.delaunay are absolutely the same. Where is the mistake?